SQL compilation error in user defined sql function in snowflake
I am writing sql user defined function in snowflake but it is throwing compilation error.Can someone please help on this?Thanks
My error is:
syntax error line 2 at position 8 unexpected 'content'. (line 40)
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_concatenate_strings(originalcontent STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS
  $$
Declare content String;
    Begin
    content := originalcontent;
    
    End;
  $$;


What is the expected input/output of the UDF?

Snowflake SQL user-defined functions are limited to executing a single SQL expression according to SQL UDFs. Something like:
CREATE FUNCTION area_of_circle(radius FLOAT)
  RETURNS FLOAT
  AS
  $$
    pi() * radius * radius
  $$
  ;

For anything more complex, you will need either a SQL stored procedure, or a UDF defined with JavaScript, Python, Java, or Scala.
