How to convert SQL statement into SQL user-defined function in snowflake?
I have a SQL statement which is working fine in snowflake, but when I converted it into an user-defined function, it is throwing an unexpected error.
This is the SQL statement which is working fine in snowflake:
Declare originalcontent String default('&quot;ezyVetReminderFuture6weeksPostcard&quot;
<br />  &quot;AnimalNextVaccinationDate_Start&quot;08-31-2026&quot;AnimalNextVaccinationDate_End&quot;
<br />  &quot;AnimalNextVaccinationName_Start&quot;DAP&quot;AnimalNextVaccinationName_End&quot;
<br />  &quot;AnimalLastVisitDate_Start&quot;09-01-2023&quot;AnimalLastVisitDate_End&quot;
<br />  &quot;AnimalNextAppointmentDate_Start&quot;&quot;AnimalNextAppointmentDate_End&quot;
<br />  &quot;AnimalSOCDueInNextYear_Start&quot;
<ul><li>Wellness Blood and Urine Screen Due on 03-13-2024</li>
<li>Wellness Exam Due on 05-13-2024</li>
</ul>&quot;AnimalSOCDueInNextYear_End&quot;');
extracttext String;
sol String;
sol_refined String;
content String;
Begin
    content := originalcontent;
    while (REGEXP_INSTR(content, '<li>')>1) do
        extracttext := SUBSTRING(content, REGEXP_INSTR(content, '<li>'), REGEXP_INSTR(content,'</li>')-REGEXP_INSTR(content, '<li>'))||'</li>';
        IF (sol IS NULL) THEN
          sol := extracttext;
        ELSE
          sol := sol || extracttext;
        END IF;

        IF (sol_refined IS NULL) THEN
            sol_refined := CASE WHEN 
            DATEDIFF('month', GETDATE(), TRY_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(RIGHT(extracttext, 15), 1, 10),'MM-DD-YYYY')) <= 3 
            THEN extracttext ELSE '' END;
        ELSE
            sol_refined := sol_refined || CASE WHEN 
            DATEDIFF('month', GETDATE(), TRY_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(RIGHT(extracttext, 15), 1, 10),'MM-DD-YYYY')) <= 3 
            THEN extracttext ELSE '' END;
        END IF;  
    
        content := replace(content,extracttext,'');
    
    end while;
    return replace(replace(replace(sol_refined,'</li><li>','|'),'<li>',''),'</li>','');
End;

Now this is converted into user defined function in snowflake and I am getting error:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_PARSE(originalcontent STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS
  $$
  Declare extracttext String;
sol String;
sol_refined String;
content String;
Begin
    content := originalcontent;
    while (REGEXP_INSTR(content, '<li>')>1) do
        extracttext := SUBSTRING(content, REGEXP_INSTR(content, '<li>'), REGEXP_INSTR(content,'</li>')-REGEXP_INSTR(content, '<li>'))||'</li>';
        IF (sol IS NULL) THEN
          sol := extracttext;
        ELSE
          sol := sol || extracttext;
        END IF;

        IF (sol_refined IS NULL) THEN
            sol_refined := CASE WHEN 
            DATEDIFF('month', GETDATE(), TRY_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(RIGHT(extracttext, 15), 1, 10),'MM-DD-YYYY')) <= 3 
            THEN extracttext ELSE '' END;
        ELSE
            sol_refined := sol_refined || CASE WHEN 
            DATEDIFF('month', GETDATE(), TRY_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(RIGHT(extracttext, 15), 1, 10),'MM-DD-YYYY')) <= 3 
            THEN extracttext ELSE '' END;
        END IF;  
    
        content := replace(content,extracttext,'');
    
    end while;
    return replace(replace(replace(sol_refined,'</li><li>','|'),'<li>',''),'</li>','');
End;
$$;

I would really appreciate help on this. Thank you

WHAT error are you getting? Remember: we can neither see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to SHOW US all the relevant info so we have any chance of helping you!

While the question is somewhat different, the resolution is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78300919/sql-compilation-error-in-user-defined-sql-function-in-snowflake/78301077#78301077

Does this answer your question? SQL compilation error in user defined sql function in snowflake

What is the expected input/output of the UDF?

@marc_s On the first part I have pasted the script that is parsing HTML and giving the value in snowflake.In second part I tried to convert the same script into user define function and it is giving error - syntax error line 2 at position 8 unexpected 'content'.Are you able to see the script I posted?

@Suman have you not read the links that either Dave Weldon or myself put in our comments? You cannot do what you are trying to do in a Function when you are using SQL Scripting
